# checksum invalid identifier in oracledb

Tags: oracle

I have a table called `host` which I can perform function aggregations like avg:

`select avg(cpu_cores) from host`

Gives me:

```
AVG(cpu_cores)
4.93
```

However if I try the same with `checksum` it errors out as invalid identifier:

`select checksum(cpu_cores) from host`

```
ORA-00904: "CHEKCSUM INVALID IDENTIFIER"
CAUSE:
ACTION:
ERROR AT LINE 1 COLUMN 8
```

why is that ?

Comment: Did you create a custom aggregate function? Or where did you find such [aggregate function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Aggregate-Functions.html#GUID-62BE676B-AF18-4E63-BD14-25206FEA0848)?

Comment: @astentx well it's not under aggregate functions you are right but still under functions https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/checksum.html

Comment: That's Oracle database version **21c** (CHECKSUM was introduced in that version). I suspect your database version isn't 21c, is it?

Comment: 19c yes. you're right